# php contact form using location.href

Tags: php, contact-form

i have created a contact form using html and php to send the email, when the user fills the forms it just display blank screen

// Let's send the email.

```
if(!$error) {
        //$messages="From: $email <br>";
        $messages.="Company Name: $name <br>";
        $messages.="Email: $email <br>";
        $messages.="Message: $message <br>";
        $emailto=$to;

        $mail = mail($emailto,$subject,$messages,"from: $from <$Reply>\nReply-To: $Reply \nContent-type: text/html");   

        if($mail) {
            $url = 'index.php?page=process&token=101'; 
                        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
                        location.href=\"$url\";
                        </script>";
                        exit; 
        }
    } else {

        echo '<div class="error">'.$error.'</div>';
    }

}
```

want if the user entered all the fields then should send them to index.php?page=process&token=101

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. There is no sense in echoing out a partial HTML page with a script tag in it when you can redirect them in PHP.

```
header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo "<script>
    window.location = '$url';
</script>";
```

I would suggest to go with `header()`, instead of java script.

Answer (score 0):

In this case instead on JavaScript best practice is use the php function for redirection. 
Try this

```
header("Location: index.php?page=process&token=101");
```